# Conditional change of text colour inside table cell

Tags: jquery, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm try to use jQuery to conditionally change the color of some table cells. I have a table:

```
<tr>
<td>Class Code</td>
<td class="qty">3</td>
<td>Science</td>
</tr>
<td>Class Code</td>
<td class="qty">4</td>
<td>Science</td>
</tr>
. . .
```

A style definition lowqty{color:red;}

I want to change the color of the second column when the number is below `4`.
I'm attempting to do that with the following, but haven't got it to work.

```
$('.qty').change(
function() {
    if ($(this).text() <= 3 ) {
        $(this).addClass('lowqty');
    }
    });
```

I've tried `3` as a string as well as a number, and I've tried filter and add in addition to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.qty').each(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).text()) < 4) {
        $(this).addClass('lowqty');
    }
});
```

That should do the trick. Also you're missing an opening TR tag:

http://jsfiddle.net/suDqH/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.val()` instead of `.text()` and that should work.

Also, you can't call a `change` event on a `table cell` - `.change()` is for `select` elements.