# how to conditionally make the background color of each td within a table to be red with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html-table

I have one example page (link removed) and one simple (from the ordinary user's view but not programmer's view) task is that making the background-color of each `td` to be red if the value therein the `()` is less or equal to 5.

Some users from this question [how can I get table row data with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48554872/how-can-i-get-table-row-data-with-jquery/) provided me example codes, however these codes are not working for my example page above.

The problem here is how to get the second table via jquery. every efforts provided from others are solely (i guess) effective for a static page with single table instance.

Comment: You need to show your efforts, Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48566895/edit) and add all relevant code that you already wrote into it. And please see **[ask]**.

Comment: what I have done was mentioned/posted in the referenced page, please check it.

Comment: You have to add all relevant code in the question itself, preferable as a runnable snippet (the `<>` button) -> [How to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional change of text colour inside table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752923/conditional-change-of-text-colour-inside-table-cell)

Comment: Thanks everyone whole commented. I have resolved this issue after reading the doc of layui.js. I need to use `done: function(){.....}` to enclose the jquery code to achieve my goal.

Comment: @Andreas Could you do me a favour to edit your image which is presented in your link? please blur the ipaddress there in. thanks.

Comment: What image? None of the links shows an image. O.o

Comment: o it is not from yours. never mind.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table td').each(
    function(){
      var td_value = $(this).text();
      if (td_value <= 5 ) {
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Full code with HTML and CSS you can find in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/oldminer/pen/LQpzzr)

UPDATE: add the regular expression:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table td').each(
    function(){
      var td_value = $(this).text();
      var regExp = /.*?\(([^)]*)\).*/;
      var matches = regExp.exec(td_value);
      if ( matches && matches[1] <= 5 ) {
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: sorry but no-go. <code>$('table').each(function(){var td_value = $(this).text(); console.log(td_value);});</code> The problem we faced is how to get the second table.

Comment: The main task in the answer was to give an algorithm for processing cells, and the selector needs to take another for its table, the selector is not the essence of the question. For now your page is down, so I can not help to write the correct selector.

Comment: @AlexanderZ. Can you have a look at my page and help?

Comment: So, my selector and script works as is - I've just paste it to console and it works. http://prntscr.com/iab5pv

Comment: I tried the code, however it ONLY works within console. I need the code work while the document/dom is loading or loaded.

Comment: First you need to make sure that jQuery is connected. Next, you need to modify the code slightly - add:  $(document).ready(function(){  ... //put here my code ...}); I have edited the code in my answer also.

Comment: Also, I have update the code and Codepen example for find numbers in parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for updates, it is really helpful with regexp.

Comment: @ Could you do me a favour to edit your image which is presented in your link? please blur the ipaddress there in. thanks.

Comment: What image do you mean?

Comment: in this link:  prntscr.com/iab5pv